# Parsing WebSocket Data?

Tags: android, websocket

I created a webSocket in android studio and I am getting the response from my server. However, when I post new data on my server, it throws an exception that prinln is null. How do I parse my websocket data?

```
public void onConnects() {

    final Thread eventThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                eventSource = new EventSource(URI.create("myUrl"), new SSEHandler(), true);
                eventSource.connect();
            }
    });
    eventThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: See [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) (The WebSocket Protocol). WebSocket and TCP socket are different things.